# Uninstalling windows security patch using python

Tags: python, windows

Does someone know how to uninstall patches generally on windows and If there is any specific way on windows server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `wusa` using the `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess
for update in ['2982791', '2988227', '1337567']:
    subprocess.run(['wusa', '/uninstall', '/kb:' + update, '/quiet'])
```